# Can't set up AP, I don't know driver name of Official Raspberry Pi Wireless dongle

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, wifi, linux-device-driver, raspberry-pi2

Recently I got the Official Raspberry Pi WiFi dongle, which has BCM43143 chipset in it. Wifi is recognised by pi, but I need the driver name for hostapd.conf

Here are the links for the product:
https://www.adafruit.com/product/2638
https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/usb-wifi-dongle/

Here is my lsmod output:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
xt_conntrack            2939  1
ipt_MASQUERADE           974  1
nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4     1901  1 ipt_MASQUERADE
iptable_nat             1787  1
nf_conntrack_ipv4      13413  2
nf_defrag_ipv4          1287  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
nf_nat_ipv4             4867  1 iptable_nat
nf_nat                 12659  2 nf_nat_ipv4,nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4
nf_conntrack           78061  5 nf_nat,nf_nat_ipv4,xt_conntrack,nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4,nf_conntrack_ipv4
iptable_mangle          1372  0
nf_log_ipv4             3849  0
nf_log_common           2941  1 nf_log_ipv4
xt_LOG                  1223  0
iptable_filter          1260  1
ip_tables              11623  3 iptable_filter,iptable_mangle,iptable_nat
x_tables               13630  6 ip_tables,ipt_MASQUERADE,xt_conntrack,xt_LOG,iptable_filter,iptable_mangle
brcmfmac              178225  0
brcmutil                5711  1 brcmfmac
cfg80211              419759  1 brcmfmac
rfkill                 16659  1 cfg80211
snd_bcm2835            19739  0
snd_pcm                74833  1 snd_bcm2835
bcm2835_gpiomem         3023  0
snd_timer              18164  1 snd_pcm
snd                    52116  3 snd_bcm2835,snd_timer,snd_pcm
uio_pdrv_genirq         2966  0
uio                     8228  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
ipv6                  341380  34
```

Note: I already tried `brcmfmac` and `cfg80211` as my driver name.

Answer (score 0):

cfg80211 is an in-kernel configuration framework, while brcmfmac is a name of FullMAC driver which implements interface required for interaction of cfg80211 with Broadcom wireless device.
Those are all Kernel concepts which exist in Kernel itself. User interaction is implemented by means of nl80211 interface.
You should set

driver=nl80211

in your hostapd.conf file.

Example can be found here https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/hostapd.